# Como resolver o erro "Can't connect to MySQL server on"?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Erro:

> ```
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql.hostinger.com.br' (111 "Connection refused") in /home/u307075603/public_html/db.php on line 8
> ```

este erro que eu recebo.

Comment: tenda adicionar o código que você esta executando, assim ajuda as pessoas a entenderem melhor o erro.

Answer (score 1):

Isso é um problema de privilégios, ou seja você não tem permissão para acessar este banco de dados.

Caso o servidor seja seu, você pode usar esta linha de comando para garantir os privilégios:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'usuario'@'mysql.hostinger.com.br' IDENTIFIED BY 'senha';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'usuario'@'mysql.hostinger.com.br'
    ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Caso não seja e você tenha comprado, provavelmente você está tentando entrar no banco de dados errado ou com um nome de usuário errado.

Comment: vou tentar beleza?

Comment: é o usuario do mysql ou da host?

Comment: Poderia me mostrar como está a linha 8?

Comment: $link = mysqli_connect('mysql.hostinger.com.br', 'user', 'senha', 'userhost', 5306);

Comment: Verifique seus parâmetros. Onde você colocou `'userhost'`, é o nome do banco de dados.

Comment: okay vou ver!!!

Comment: resolveu um dos erros, mais tem outro erro

Comment: e ta dizendo que não esta conseguindo conectar ao MySql Server

Comment: Poderia por favor copiar o colar o erro, para eu entender melhor?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host 'u307075603_zeref' (-5) in /home/u307075603/public_html/db.php on line 8

Comment: Como a linha 8 está agora?

Comment: $link = mysqli_connect('31.170.167.225', 'user', 'senha', 'u307075603_zeref', 5306);

Comment: Cara, seus parâmetros estão preenchidos corretamente. Ou é um problema no servidor `31.170.167.225` ou você está errando o nome do banco.

Comment: é o servidor, mais aqui está escrito olha ai

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fqf75u

Comment: ve a print ai e me fala se eu tenho que colocar mysql.hostinger.com.br

Comment: Cara, se seu domínio na hostinger é aqueles gratuitos, pode desistir vc não vai conseguir conectar...